# How do I get Custom Variables in Google Analytics to work using Async method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, google-analytics, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I'm researching how to use Google Analytics by applying it to a test site I've built using VB.NET and MVC5. I'm using the Async method since that seems to be what the Google Developers site is recommending.

In my _Layout.vbhtml (which Visual Studio automatically generated for me) I have the following code between my `<head>` and `</head>` tags:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
<script>
    window.ga = window.ga || function () { (ga.q = ga.q || []).push(arguments) }; ga.l = +new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-75489237-2', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<script>
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
        5,                  // This custom var is set to slot #5.  Required parameter.
        'CusVarTest',       // The top-level name for your online content categories.  Required parameter.
        'Successful',       // Sets the value of "Section" to "Life & Style" for this particular aricle.  Required parameter.
        3                   // Sets the scope to page-level.  Optional parameter.
    ]);
</script>
</head>
```

Now, theoretically, this should be working, but when I go to the Google Analytics site, and go to "Reporting --> Audience --> Custom --> Custom Variables" I am seeing no sign of my variable.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. you are mixing older classic GA syntax (`_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', ...`) with the new UA syntax (`ga('create', 'UA-75489237-2', 'auto');`). That's not going to work. I advise you to make sure you are using only UA code.
2. Custom Variables have been phased out of UA, so you will need to use the UA analogs called "Custom dimensions" (cf. https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en). This includes no longer using the Custom Variables in the reports.
3. data takes up to 24 hours to process, so you won't see things right away in your reports unless you wait a day, or you could try using GA Debugger or console tools to verify that your data is properly set and sent.

Comment: 4. Both custom vars (old syntax) and custom dimension need to be set before the pageview, or at least before an interaction hit or they will not be transmitted to GA (and custom dimensions are not a perfect analogue to custom vars since you cannot not access them in clientside code, but that makes no difference for this use case).